# Visual/audio status/activity indicators

Tags: peripherals, led

What, if any, indicators of system status or activity are available on the Pi?

Audio - I'm talking about a beep when it's turned off, or a series of beeps indicating POST information, etc.

Video - Does it have a power on LED? What about a disk activity LED, like you get on the front panel of a lot of PCs etc.

If none, are there any peripheral options available to connect via USB in order to present such information?

I am considering a headless project for use in-car, (continuous loop recording of audio, parking sensors etc). And I would like to know that it's working without having to login etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Pi does not have any onboard speaker, so there are no power on/off sounds. The main indicators are the lights on the front corner of the board. These are:

- OK (green): The board is active (blinks off when accessing the SD card)
- PWR (red): The board is successfully powered from USB
- FDX (green): Network is full-duplex
- LNK (green): The network cable is connected (blinks off when transferring data to/from the network)
- 10M (yellow): Lit when the board is using a 100Mbps link, **not** lit when using a 10Mbps

Comment: The 10M is incorrectly marked on the board - it's should be 100M and should be lit on a 100Mbps connection.

Comment: You're right... I knew that and got it the wrong way round, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no audio beep.

There is a red power LED. There is a green SD Card activity LED. There are LEDs for the network interface. None of them are best placed to take out to the surface of a case.

However, it is relatively easy to connect some LED's to the GPIO and write a script to turn them on & off on at various stages of booting and/or running.